# AssociatedType in a protocol with typealias

Tags: ios, swift

Lets say i have a protocol:

```
protocol Router {
    associatedtype Answer
    typealias AnswerCallback = (Answer) -> Void
}
```

At some point I want to store a variable of type AnswerCallback

```
var answerCallback: Router.AnswerCallback ...
```

But I need to specify which concrete type i'm using since i get this error:

> Type alias 'AnswerCallback' can only be used with a concrete type or
>   generic parameter base

How I can specify a type like Router.AnswerCallback ... where String is "Answer" type?

Instead the only way to work is to use         `var answerCallback: ((String) -> Void)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a class/struct that conforms to `Router`, which has an `Answer` of `String`:

```
class StringRouter : Router {
    typealias Answer = String
}

let callback: StringRouter.AnswerCallback? = nil
```

If all you want is such a type alias, you don't need a protocol:

```
typealias AnswerCallback<T> = (T) -> Void
```